# Pointing a parked subdomain to a real subdomain

Tags: domains, cpanel, multiple-domains, httpd.conf, httpd

I have two registered domains. Say the domains are `originaldomain.com` and `parkeddomain.com`.

`parkeddomain.com` points to `originaldomain.com`.

I also have a few subdomains in `originaldomain.com`, and I want to be able to do this:

- `subdomain1.originaldomain.com` -> `subdomain1.originaldomain.com`
- `subdomain2.originaldomain.com` -> `subdomain2.originaldomain.com`

And so on.

Problem is, I can't figure out through cPanel, or WHM how to do this, if it is possible.
I also went through **httpd.conf** , and changed *ServerAlias* under the *VirtualHost* of `subdomain1.originaldomain.com`.

So what I have is:

```
<VirtualHost .....:80>
ServerName subdomain1.originaldomain.com
ServerAlias www.subdomain1.originaldomain.com subdomain1.parkeddomain.com subdomain1.parkeddomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/originaldomain/public_html/subdomain1
...
</VirtualHost>
```

I then restarted `httpd`, using `service httpd restart`, but nothing seems to work.

P.S.: I'm using CentOS 5.3.

Comment: You want subdomain1.parkedomain.com to point to subdomain1.originaldomain.com and so one? Right now your question is confusing. There is no point in redirecting subdomain1.originaldomain.com to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change some NS or A Records for each entry.

Here is an example.

> My domain is johnbhatt.com and have hosting. Another Domain is
>   pyarb.com and is only a domain name.
>
> I forwarded all visitors to johnbhatt.com and each sub-domain like,
>   store.pyarb.com is pointing to store.johnbhatt.com and same for other
>   sub-domains also.

I have just updated the Name servers as below.

`pyarb.com` points to `ns21.hostdatasecure.com` and `ns21.hostdatasecure.com`.
And to point to hosting page, I used A records for each domain.

I use Windows hosting and I have added a Domain Alias in control pannel for domain but didn't tried with subdomains in Linux hosting.

You can check details with below link.
http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=dnsrec&host=johnbhatt.com

Comment: Glad to know that you got solution.